# windows xp (sp 3), keyboard, installation

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, installation, sp3

I'm trying to install Windows XP (SP3).  My PS/2 keyboard works in BIOS but when I want to install Windows and there is a screen when I'm supposed to hit enter, my keyboard is frozen, and doesn't react.

Any hints?

Comment: thanks for repply,

But id didnt help, Keybord stops responding when windows loaded all files and switches to "press enter to continue, press r to repair installation ...  " screen,

aby other solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem once and it was because of wireless presenter USB (that emulates keyboard). In BIOS I had legacy USB keyboard support enabled and, for some reason, BIOS defaulted to USB instead of PS/2. PS/2 keyboard would work for entering BIOS but once anything boots it would stop working.

Solution would be to disable USB keyboard support (or just unplug USB device causing trouble).

Another solution might be BIOS update (if one is available).

Answer (score 0):

Get a ps2 to usb converter? I keep one for these situations.